# Motionbuilder Animation to After Effects

Tags: after-effects, fbx

Not sure if its possible but I have an animation (.fbx) file in Motionbuilder that I want to import into After Effects so that each bone from in MotionBuilder can be turned into an animated null.

Answer (score 0):

You can import FBX files into Cinema 4D and then use the .c4d scene file in After Effects.

Comment: I tried that in CC but it doesn't look like it does anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can import FBX format scene file in After Effects
or convert obj and install 3d element
other tutorial in [after effects site](http://clean-theme.com/category/after-effects/)

Answer (score -1):

Any chance you can export Motionbuilder data to BVH? If so, the [BVH Importer](http://aescripts.com/bvh-importer/) is probably the only way to go to make it work with AE.